# How to Continuously Run a Python Script for Date-Based Notifications

Tags: python, notifications

I've created a Python script that interacts with Excel to send notifications to my phone when the current date matches a due date in an Excel file. The script works as intended when manually executed in VSCode.

I need this script to run continuously (or check regularly) so that it can automatically send notifications without manual intervention. I've considered using Windows Task Scheduler to achieve this, but I'm unsure if this is the best approach or how to set it up correctly for continuous operation.

How can I configure my Python script to run in such a way that it consistently checks the date and sends notifications without needing to start it manually each time? Are there better alternatives to Windows Task Scheduler for this purpose, or specific configurations within it that I should use?

Comment: Using Windows Task Scheduler is perfectly fine. Especially if you're running your Python script at regular intervals on a Windows system.

Answer (score 1):

Using Windows Task Scheduler is perfectly fine. The correct way to do it is basically:

- Open Task Scheduler
- in the "Triggers" tab, you want to set up the task to start upon start or logon, and repeat every X minutes/hours.
- In the "Actions" tab, you will choose your `.py` file.

Also, there are some other approaches in case you would prefer scheduling task within your Python file. There are many libraries, the one that I was using before is `schedule`, installation is basic:

```
pip install schedule
```

You'd have to modify your code of course, pure example:

```
import schedule
import time

def check_and_notify():
    # Your code to check the date and send notifications

# Schedule to run every hour
schedule.every().hour.do(check_and_notify)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

You can also run it as a Windows service. For that you'd use the `pywin32` library - after installing pywin32, you can set up your script as a service that Windows can start at boot and keep running - it's kind of more complex to setup and doing debugging is also a bit complex.

There's also Docker in case you're familiar with it, using third party apps, or even cloud-based schedulers like AWS Lambda with CloudWatch Events.